# imagebutton image url not changed dynamic on repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, imagebutton

I am using repeater to bind data & on header template i am using imagebutton for sorting column.

**My Client Side Code:**

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptClientDetails" OnItemDataBound="RptClientDetails_ItemDataBound">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <table id="example" class="dynamicTable table table-striped table-bordered table-primary">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                Client Name
                                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ImgbtnNameUp" ImageUrl="~/Images/BlackUp.png"
                                                    OnCommand="lbtnSortingAccending_Click" CommandArgument="Name" Height="15px" Width="20px" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ImgbtnNameUpDown" ImageUrl="~/Images/BlackDown.png"
                                                    OnCommand="lbtnSorting_Click" CommandArgument="Name" Height="15px" Width="20px" />
                                            </th>
                                            <th>
                                                Total Balance Due
                                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ImgbtnTotalBalanceDueUp" ImageUrl="~/Images/BlackUp.png"
                                                    OnCommand="lbtnSortingAccending_Click" CommandArgument="TotalBalanceDue" Height="15px"
                                                    Width="20px" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ImgbtnTotalBalanceDueDown" ImageUrl="~/Images/BlackDown.png"
                                                    OnCommand="lbtnSorting_Click" CommandArgument="TotalBalanceDue" Height="15px"
                                                    Width="20px" />
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>


                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
```

**On C# Code:**

```
protected void lbtnSorting_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExpression = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    List<ARDTO> SirtlingListOBj = (List<ARDTO>)Session["GetClientList"];
    int Showall = (int)Session["ShowAll"];

    ImageButton imgBtnobj = new ImageButton();
    imgBtnobj = (ImageButton)sender;
    imgBtnobj.ImageUrl = "";
    imgBtnobj.ImageUrl = "/Images/greenDown.png";
}
```

Here i want to change ImageURl... But it's not working...
So, any body can help me here...

**What's wrong here ?**

**or can i change it via css ?**

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick without having to worry about the rendered names.

The Datalist is handled on the serverside so that the ImageUrl path is completely rendered. this should leave a nice simple OnClientClick call to the jquery at the bottom which sets the Image1 src.

Also, I didn't see the actual call to the SimpleModal plugin, so I added it to the JS as I couldn't see how you were getting any sort of popup at all based on the code snippets

```
   <div id="basic-modal-content">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="" runat="server" />
</div>

<div id='container'>
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ThumbnailImg" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("n1") %>' Height="100" Width="150" BorderStyle="Ridge" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowFullImg(this);" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowFullImg(e)
    {
        $('#basic-modal-content img').attr('src',$(e).attr('src'))
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal()
    }
</script>
```